# After creating feature(using feature project) in Eclipse, how to zip it with a folder(in filesystem) so that I can use that folder through the plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have developed a plug-in. And I am using Feature Project to install it in eclipse as I want this plugin to be installed on different computers also.

I want to use a *folder*(which is in the file system) in my plugin. Now that I want to make use of this plugin on different computers, how can I pack(or zip/jar) my feature along with the *folder* so that my plugin would be able to use this folder.

And how will I get the location where I am unzipping the *folder* on different computers?

Note: I don't want this folder in my source code project.

Comment: What is the purpose of that folder? Does it contain user-specific, external data, or resources to be used by your plugin? In the latter case, it should definitely be bundled with your plugin (into that plugin). In the first case, you should perhaps make that folder configurable by the user, using an Eclipse Preferences extension.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht The folder contains the resources used by my plugin. Can you tell me how do I bundle it with my plugin? Is it not possible bundling it without keeping it in my plugin?

Comment: You can add files / folders to the install using directives in the feature build.properties (see [here](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_rootfiles.htm). You can't add anything outside of the install.

Comment: For resources you just use a folder in your plugin and include that folder in the plugin's build.properties. Use the `FileLocator` class to find the resources in your code.

Comment: @greg-449 Oh. I read through it. But I didn't quite understand what to write in my feature build.properties. Can you tell me what to write if the folder I want to bundle is in the location, say, D:/myfolder? Currently, my feature build.properties has **bin.includes = feature.xml** in it

Comment: You can't put things in a location that is not part of the install.

Comment: @greg-449 But feature _is_ a part of my install